# Bullet point character level 2 not appear when convert HTML to PDF with Symfony 2

Tags: php, html, symfony, pdf

In symfony 2 i'm using h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 for convert HTML to PDF.
Actually in production and preproduction i have big square with "NO GLYPH" writting inside instead of level 2 bullet point.
This probleme not appear in local source while the source same than prod and preprod.

This is an exemple of my HTML code :

```
<ul style="list-style-type: undefined;">
        <li>
            <span class="textRed" style="color: #ff0000;">
                Etablir une relation bas&eacute;e sur l'empathie
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="textBlue" style="color: #0000ff;">
                        D&eacute;finition
                    </span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span class="textBlue textVert" style="color: #009900;">
                                Compr&eacute;hension des &eacute;motions et des sentiments
                            </span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="textBlue textVert" style="color: #009900;">
                                &ne; compassion
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
I use wkhtmltopdf for transform HTML to PDF.

When wkhtmltopdf not found a glyph, it use the default font of the server. In my case, there isn't default font so i upload and use DejaVu and it works!